# Extract multiple zip files recursively using 7z script file

Tags: windows, cmd, 7zip

I have a folder which has multiple zip files in multiple folders and I would like to extract it all by using a script file

I went over the answer from stack overflow from here https://superuser.com/questions/248287/extract-recursively-using-7-zip

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %a in (`DIR /s /b *.zip`) do 7z.exe e %a
```

and it is extracting well, the problem is that it is extracting all files to the root folder, and I want every zip to be extracted in it's original folder next to the .zip file

meaning next to `\folder\file.zip`
I will have

```
\folder\file.zip
\folder\content_of_zip.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`7z` includes a switch to indicate where to extract the files. We can use it to indicate the drive and path of the file being referenced by the `for` command.

```dos
for /r %a in (*.zip) do 7z.exe e "%~a" -o"%~dpa"
```

Comment: Hi, 
I want to "replace the existing file" with the file from the archive. I get following options -
"yes/No/Always/Skip all/Rename all/Quit"
How can I achieve this thru command line itself instead of manually?